# How can I repair Ubuntu software center ?

Tags: software-center

Please look what comes out when I launch it:

[Message when I launch, before I do any thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7lCe.png)

After I click on **repair** and authenticate, it runs the reparation process and before it complete, it stops and display this message:[Message of failure on reparation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn90r.png)

Now when I press okay, it returns to the first message and all this start again over and over.

What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: Try re-installing....Open Terminal ctrl-T, sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: I tried this but still have the same problem